# Node.js - Does iterating with a for loop ensure my callbacks are called one after another in order?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Apologies if the title is a little undescriptive - however I often come across this problem and wonder what the correct way to handle this situation is:

- I have an array/some list, I want to iterate through and run call some methods that have callbacks to subsequent steps. Would all the callbacks be processed? And would they be done so in order:

To be more specific, here is an example:

1 - I've created this array called files containing the paths of some dmg files in a folder:

```
var files = []

walker.on('file', function(root, stat, next) {
    if (stat.name.indexOf(".dmg") > -1) {
        files.push(root + '/' + stat.name);
    } 
    next();
});
```

2 - I then want to iterate through, upload something, then after the upload send a message to a RabbitMQ queue:

```
for (var bk = 0; bk < files.length; bk ++) {

    var uploader = client.uploadFile(params);
    uploader.on('error', function (err) {
        console.error("unable to upload:", err.stack);
    });
    uploader.on('progress', function () {
        console.log("progress", uploader.progressMd5Amount,
            uploader.progressAmount, uploader.progressTotal);
    });
    uploader.on('end', function () {
        console.log("done uploading");

        //Now send the message to RabbitMQ
        myRabbitMQObject.then(function (conn) {
          return conn.createChannel();
        }).then(function (ch) {
          return ch.assertQueue(q).then(function (ok) {
            return ch.sendToQueue(q, new Buffer("Some message with path from the files array"));
        });
        }).catch(console.warn);

    });

}
```

Now the bit I'm always unsure of is if I placed the block of code under 2 around a for loop - as that has callbacks inside, are these guaranteed to  get called?

In this example I don't really care about the order - however if I did care about the order, will having it in a for loop ensure the uploading and rabbitmq messages are sent one after another?

I hope the question makes sense.

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Where's the `for` loop?  You show some code, but no `for` loop anywhere.  I guess you kind of describe where it might be in your words, but it would be a whole lot clearer if you showed the actual `for` loop you're asking about.

Comment: It would go around the block of code in part 2 - i'll add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop runs synchronously.  In your code, what that means is that it will execute the line:

```
var uploader = client.uploadFile(params);
```

one after another starting all the uploads.  It won't wait for the first one to finish before it starts all of them.  So, think of your `for` loop as initiating a whole bunch of asynchronous operations.

Then, sometime later, one by one, in no guaranteed order, each of your uploads will finish.  They will essentially all by "in flight" at the same time.  Each of your rabbitMQ operations will happen whenever their corresponding upload finishes.  The `for` loop will long since be over at that point and the MQ operations will be in no particular order.

Your current code has no way of telling when everything is done.

> I have an array/some list, I want to iterate through and run call some methods that have callbacks to subsequent steps. Would all the callbacks be processed? And would they be done so in order?

All the events will get triggered and you event handler callbacks will get called.  They will not be done in any guaranteed order.

> Now the bit I'm always unsure of is if I placed the block of code under 2 around a for loop - as that has callbacks inside, are these guaranteed to get called?

Yes.  Your callbacks will get called.  The `for` launches each upload and, at some point, they will all trigger their events which will call your event handler callbacks.

> In this example I don't really care about the order - however if I did care about the order, will having it in a for loop ensure the uploading and rabbitmq messages are sent one after another?

The `for` loop will ensure that the uploads are started in sequence.  But, the finish order is not guaranteed so therefore the rabbitmq messages that you send upon finish may be in any order.  If you want the rabbitmq messages to be sent in a particular order or want the uploads to be sequenced, then you need more/different code to make that happen.

Comment: Thanks for that description - so even though as you say `The for loop will long since be over` the callbacks will still be inflight waiting to be completed? i.e. I can rest assured that the message to rabbitmq would be sent - although the order wouldnt be certain

Comment: also wanted to ask, any variables I decalred in teh for loop - would they be specific to that particular iteration?

Comment: @userMod2 - Variables declared with `var` are scoped to the containing function are are NOT unique to the particular iteration of the loop (one variable with that name per function).  Variables declared with `let` or `const` are unique to the particular iteration of the loop because they are block scoped (not function scoped) so they would be scoped to the block of the `for` loop and each iteration of the loop would make a new `let` or `const` variable.

Comment: @userMod2 - As long as nothing else specifically kills your uploads, they will carry on with their normal processing and triggering their events.  The `for` loop doesn't really have anything to do with that.  It just initiates the operations and then they have a life of their own independent of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is my understanding. it might help you

- Iterating over list of files and calling upload function is synchronous. It will maintain order
- Updating RabbitMQ on successful completion of upload does not guarantee order as it is asynchronous and completion of upload depends on size of file and network latency during upload.